# Show how much time is left after later.js text parser applied

Tags: javascript, laterjs

How to display what time is left after the [later.js text parser](https://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html#text) applied?

For example, I want to know it before the `setInterval` started.

```
const later = require('later');

later.date.localTime();
const schedule = later.parse.text('at 12:40');

later.setInterval(() => {
    console.log('executed!');
}, schedule);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [.next()](https://bunkat.github.io/later/occurrences.html#instances) method which calculates the future occurrences.

**Display the future occurrence**

Input:

```
console.log(later.schedule(schedule).next());
```

Output:

```
2017-11-28T12:40:00.000Z
```

**Display 10 future occurrences**

Input

```
console.log(later.schedule(schedule).next(10));
```

Output

```
[ 2017-11-28T12:40:00.000Z,
  2017-11-29T12:40:00.000Z,
  2017-11-30T12:40:00.000Z,
  2017-12-01T12:40:00.000Z,
  2017-12-02T12:40:00.000Z,
  2017-12-03T12:40:00.000Z,
  2017-12-04T12:40:00.000Z,
  2017-12-05T12:40:00.000Z,
  2017-12-06T12:40:00.000Z,
  2017-12-07T12:40:00.000Z ]
```